# Django/Python - upload custom scripts - how to run them?

Tags: python, django, popen

I have a `Django` project which parses XML feeds. The thing is that I often need to write a custom script to parse or download a new feed/s for a new client.

I don't think the best way is to modify `Django` code every time I need a custom parsing/downloading pipeline.

My idea is to create a standard. For example, I upload `myscript.py` through Admin, which must have the class `class Downloader()` with function `download(self)` and this function will be called every time that source has to be downloaded.

So what is the most common way to do that?

The only thing which comes to my mind is to upload `myscript.py` which has `if __name__ == '__main__'` function and call it by for example `Popen('python filename.py')`

or

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "filename.py"])
```

model:

```
class Source(..):
    custom_downloader = FileField(... # if needed
    ...
```

Comment: You can place it in a callback of a Django signal and emit the signal somewhere in a view, or you can make to be called in Celery task. You can call it `subprocess.call("myscript.py", shell=True)` if you don't want to import it and use directly.

Comment: There are good reasons not to mix up data and code.

Comment: @KlausD. What I'm trying to do is not to have to modify server code every time a new customer has some feed which has its own way to download or parse. How would you do that?

Comment: Have a smart deployment system to change the code fastly. Do not allow customers to upload any code. That would be a security disaster.

Comment: @KlausD. No no, it's my code and only me/system can execute it. Just it seems better to be able to upload it through admin.